# location for application text file not in home directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, flatpak

I use linux. I'm working on a project where an app I wrote is launched by my runlauncher. At that time the app looks for an environment variable on the sytem. This environment variable contains a path to a text json file. I want to put this file somewhere on the sytem, not in the home directory. Where would be the appropriate place?

The environment variable is GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. The app is a flatpak app.

TLDR: Where do I put things on the system that I can read from my application that are not in the home directory?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you need super-user rights (or `sudo`) if you want to write file outside $HOME directory. If you have only user right, then only $HOME directory is writable.